# What material to use for cosmetic red brick touch ups outside?

Tags: repair, brick, hole

There are some holes in the brickwork on the outside of my house from unneeded cable clips, anchors and DIY jobs gone bad.

Nothing structurally significant but I do want to achieve a cleaner look.

Maybe some paste I can smear over the holes? If there is such a thing, how is it called so I can buy some?
Or maybe I can make something myself?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to be red rather than just using some mortar touch up material?  I think using mortar would look fine.

Comment: of course it has to be red. Ideally something I can mix in some paint to come closer to the surrounding color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would find color-matched urethane caulk. You'd be able to easily apply it with the nozzle and it's dead-reliable. Companies that make fibercement siding often have an array of colors available.